# Xamarin Service behavior according to some business rules

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, service

I'm creating a service that works independent of the app and sends notifications according to some business rules.

The problem is: if the app is open, depending on which activity is open, I can not do anything, but the default action is to open a specific activity.

I can not find any similar example or problem to study...

Any idea?

Comment: Can you express the problem clearly? I cant  understand what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm sorry for the poor english.

Try to create your handlers methods as static in your "App" class and manage the behavior of your app since that point. Think about to use some events to handle specifics changes (as notify with a "new" badge on view, if you want).

I don't have a independent service, but I'm working in an app that once a user is logged in, it starts a background service to monitore battery, updates, user properties changes... and this solution works well.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not what I need, I already did it and it did not work as I expected. In your case, that's fine because the application is always working so the context is always known. In my case I do not always know the context, so I do not know how to manipulate the activities stack.

Comment: Que tipo de notificação e em que momento, por exemplo, você precisa entregar para o usuário? Qual ação o a notificação deverá ter? Acho que não entendi corretamente sua questão.